# Sort list by checked/unchecked state

Tags: org-mode, list

I was wondering if org-mode offers a function to sort a list by the item states? So that checked items appear on top and unchecked items at the bottom? For example with this list

```
- [ ] Not yet done
- [x] Already done
- [ ] Not yet done
- [x] Already done
- [ ] Not yet done
- [x] Already done
- [ ] Not yet done
- [x] Already done
```

I would get this list:

```
- [x] Already done
- [x] Already done
- [x] Already done
- [x] Already done
- [ ] Not yet done
- [ ] Not yet done
- [ ] Not yet done
- [ ] Not yet done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org-sort` (bound to <kbd>C-c ^</kbd>) on a plain list will prompt for the sort method. One of the sorting options is *[x]checked*.

So <kbd>C-c ^ x</kbd> will do the job.

If you want to sort the items from checked to unchecked, use a capital <kbd>X</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Org has the function, but since the list is well-organized,
you can simply use Emacs' sorting commands (see
[(info "(emacs) Sorting")](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sorting.html))

If you don't mind changing exiting order, select the list and `M-x sort-lines`, this command simply sorts lines in region alphabetically. If you mind, you can use **one** of the following two methods.

- Select the region from the first `[` to the last `]` and `C-u M-x sort-columns`
- Select the list and type `C-u M-x sort-regexp-fields RET ^.*$ RET \[.\] RET`

(Note that `- [ ]` is lexicographically smaller than `- [x]` since ASCII code of  (white space) is 32 and `x`'s is 120).